# Create menu within the Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to create Floating Action Button with other menu options like below.[image]

I have downloaded this image from Google. But i am not getting any demo or way to achieve this type of effect to open submenu from the Floating Action Button.

I have found another library which has the same effect but I don't want to use another library, rather I'd like to implement it myself. Just need proper guidance how to do this.

Please let me know if there is proper explanation for implementing same is available.

For reference you can check this link: http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button

For More information same effect is also available in [inbox app by google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox&hl=en).

Comment: https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu you can use satellite menu for this instead of FAB

Comment: @AmrutBidri thanks for reply. But i want to use the Defauot android code. Dont want to use other's library. Please let me know if you know how the effect is occurs.

Comment: Not everything that is in a Google app is provided in the Android SDK. Some of the UI widgets are custom code written by Google. Even the FAB is not a standard widget. People have given you examples of libraries that implement this design. There are even more on GitHub. You can either use one of these libraries, or look at the code and implement it yourself.

Comment: @Kiliman I completely agree with you.But please read my question carefully, I need login or concept for how to create such effect.

Comment: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button This one works just like Google Inbox. If you don't want to use this library, look at the code to see how it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to depend on others library. That's why I am looking for someone who have make the same with the animation and effect, not with the library.

I have made my own demo here in below link:

[FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/ShreyashPromact/FloatingActionButtonDemo)

Here you can change the animation you want and also add one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for the floating menu buttons-
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/965

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i dont want to use other library. I want to implement it by own. Just need concept or idea for how to create such app. FYI, same effect is available in the inbox app by google.